# Vagrant up hangs on clearing any previously set network interfaces

Tags: windows-10, vagrant, cygwin, virtualbox, centos7

I'm trying to create a VM CentOS7 using Vagrant (2.2.3) and Virtual Box (5.2.24), on Windows 10 and via CygWin.

Following the Vagrant Cloud istructions (https://app.vagrantup.com/centos/boxes/7), I've done the following command

```
vagrant init centos/7
```

This command generate a `Vagrantfile` in my directory.

Using the command ...

```
vagrant up
```

... all works fine, but if I change my `Vagrantfile` to fix an IP address in this way

```
  # Create a private network, which allows host-only access to the machine
  # using a specific IP.
   config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.33.10"
```

when I use the command ...

```
vagrant up
```

... the execution stops with this output

```
$ vagrant up
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> default: Importing base box 'centos/7'...
==> default: Matching MAC address for NAT networking...
==> default: Checking if box 'centos/7' version '1901.01' is up to date...
==> default: Setting the name of the VM: Tmp
==> default: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
```

and does not complete.

Any suggestion will be appreciated!